# Credits for images from research papers in SE

Tags: discussion

Stack exchange publishes the question/answer posts with a credit common license.

In research conference slides, it is very common to use images from papers  provided we add a credit, even if the image cannot be shared officially because of the publisher policy. In papers, we don't hack the figures because it is the publisher's responsibility.

SE does not seem to run actively after any image credit violations.  There are some discussions on Meta about it (eg. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101802/should-images-be-accompanied-with-licensing-info)).

Do you think it would be *tolerated* to add images in our SE site from papers which are protected under a pay-wall (example in my post [here](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/low-cost-recording-of-whitefly-vibrations-piezo-versus-low-noise-microphone)) provided on citing the reference correctly? In research, authors are usually happy to see their figures be used if cited and I wonder if the publishers really care about it. In practice, could we just wait for potential complains or should we strictly not use them?

Comment: This discussion about posting figures to twitter might be interesting to those interested in this question...although its specific to your OWN figures:
https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/188239/am-i-allowed-to-post-screenshots-of-tables-figures-of-my-paper-on-twitter

Answer (score 1):

As an author, I would not mind. From a copyright stand point, I think it *should* be ok because it is all for educational purposes and not for profit? But I am not a publisher :)

Comment: I agree with what you say as an author, Selene. One comment, though: Stack Exchange is not an educational institution nor a charity, it's a profit-making business. Thus, for example, it would probably be inappropriate to use images on SE if they are published under a Creative Commons "Non-commercial" licence ... even though the user who posted it is not making a profit! Most academic papers would not have this problem though.

Comment: That's really interesting distinction - thanks for pointing it out @DanStowell. So you are saying most academic papers would not have this problem - meaning they wouldn't have an issue with being posted on SE?

Comment: Yes, that's right